# How to document RcppExports.R linking functions?

Tags: r, rcpp, roxygen2

In my `RcppExports.R`, things look like this:

```
# This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
# Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393

rcppeigen_ftrans <- function(A) {
    .Call('mypkg_rcppeigen_ftrans', PACKAGE = 'mypkg', A)
}
```

I try to document my code like this:

```
# This file was generated by Rcpp::compileAttributes
# Generator token: 10BE3573-1514-4C36-9D1C-5A225CD40393
# 
#' Fast Matrix Transpose
#' 
#' (description)
#' @param ...
#'

rcppeigen_ftrans <- function(A) {
    .Call('mypkg_rcppeigen_ftrans', PACKAGE = 'mypkg', A)
}
```

Whenever I hit the `document` button, `roxygen2` automatically runs 
`Rcpp::compileAttributes()` and then this file gets regenerated without
documentation. I also tried to manually write
the `.Rd` documentation files, but again when I hit `document`, the `.Rd`
file gets deleted. I want to document these linking functions, but don't know how to.

Comment: Put the roxygen documentation in the source Cpp file.

Comment: @hadley genius as always! Thank you so much!

Comment: Folks, there are over 430 packages using Rcpp on CRAN. _These are working examples. Use them._ Also, search is a search box at the top here and `[r] [rcpp] [roxygen]` would almost sure have provided a hint.

Answer (score 4):

i.e. to be precise, in your `code.cpp` file:

```
//' Fast Matrix Transpose
//' 
//' Description
//' @param m
//' ... etc
IntegerMatrix fasttr(IntegerMatrix m) {
```